Is it possible to perform a weight measurement of a 200kg object with 0.1g precision, in the range of 199.5kg to 200kg only?
I want to precisely measure the weight change of a 200kg object in an indoor lab setting. The total weight change from start to end of the experiment is only 0.5kg.
I would ideally need a scale that can give me a measurement every 10 seconds. This leads to a needed precision of 0.1g.
I was unable to find scales with a weight limit of 200kg or more and a precision better than 1g.
I have access to lab scales with the desired precision but maximum weight capacities of only a few Kilos at most.
However, the scale does not need to be precise over the whole range of 200kg, only over a range of 0.5kg.
I already tried a simple approach, where I attached the object I want to weigh to a lever and used a counterweight to reduce the load on the scale to only ~1kg. Unfortunately this introduces errors in the order of grams to the measurement. (I believe mostly due to friction losses in the ball bearing used to attach the lever.)
Are there any known approaches to this problem?

A real mechanical scales use a very sharp thin hard surface (called a knife) as a pivot. So no i dont expect a pulley to be accurate. Sesaw with very little movement balanced on a knife edge is a different thing.

Is it possible? is a useless question because the answer is almost always a yes

@jsotola thank you very much for the insight. I have a follow-up question though: "How is it possible?"

I was thinking about this and did a little searching on the web and got the phrase: This presents a significant technical challenge.  I don't think much of people who declare something impossible because they don't know how to do it without anything more than that.  I believe you will find this to be, if not impossible, not practicably implementable.
The story that I tell from time to time is:

Years ago, my PhD boss wanted to have a big clear vessel to allow
watching some convection heat flow.  There were two constraints, it had
to be big enough to contain the apparatus and it had to handle the
temperatures.  We called and called and found lots
of companies that sold glassware that could
handle the temperatures and lots that sold clear vessels that were big
enough but none that could meet both requirements.  The boss changed
his plans a little and as I recall, we got it implemented with a steel
vessel with a window, he did not have the visibility he wanted but we
got it running.

What you have already tried is to pull up with 199.5kg and weigh what remains.   As you observed, a pulley won't cut it.  As submitted by @joojaa, a knife edge balance will allow fine measurements.  A knife edge balance has two opposing constraints,

The sharper the edge, the more precise the measurements can be.
The sharper the edge, the lower the surface area supporting the weight so the higher the pressure on the edge.

If you have an edge that can functionally apply 199.5kg, it will have difficulty with the area of the pivot.  Will it move when 0.1g is applied?  I have no clue. I think you are going to have trouble with this.
That said, here's a goofy, unworkable idea, suppose you had a big helium balloon pulling up with 199.5 kg (plus or minus 0.1g) force?  You'd have to calibrate the balloon if the temperature or barometric pressure changed but within a bunch of ten second measurements, the results would be consistent.  Let's see, you'd need a balloon about ten meters in diameter.  You DO have a monster gymnasium available to run the experiment, no? (I did say it was unworkable.)
My suggestion is to decide how long you are willing to play trying to get a knife edge counterweight to do what you need and when that time is up, redesign things.

You could utilize buoyancy to make this object "lighter" and then combine this with small precise hanging scale. Since you will probably need to use some kind of vessel for the object, you will also need to have a conversion for measured values. The best would probably be something prismatic like a cylinder, which does not change cross-section when lifted a bit.
